# Direct Comparison Test (Divergence)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = \frac{9^n}{n + 5^n}$.

At large $n$ value, $a_n$ is expected to behave like $\frac{9^n}{5^n}$, therefore it diverges.

Using the direct comparison test, how can I find $b_n$ (has to be smaller than $a_n$ to prove that $a_n$ diverges)?

Comment: Hi! I've used MathJax to make your post a bit easier to read. I encourage you to do the same for future questions (see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some tips about it). And since you are a new user, you might be interested in [this other link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about the question format (not that there is anything particularly bad about your post).

Comment: @Alicia Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

By Binomial Theorem $5^{n}=(1+4)^{n}=1+4n+...+4^{n}>1+4n >n$ so $\frac {9^{n}} {n+5^{n}} >  \frac {9^{n}} {2(5^{n})}$. Take $b_n=\frac {9^{n}} {2(5^{n})}$.

Comment: This is also known as Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that, what do I do after this? How do I evaluate if this is divergent or convergent?

Comment: @Alicia The geometric series $\sum (\frac 9 5)^{n}$ is divergent because the  common ratio $ \frac 9 5$ exceeds $1$.

Comment: Yes, but since this is bigger than the original series, it won't be valid to compare no?

Comment: @Alicia Read my answer carefully. The original series is bigger than the new series $\sum b_n$, not the other way.

Comment: Oh right, sorry my bad! Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_n \ge \frac{1}{n}$  for all $n$.

Comment: Hi! How did you get that? Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is about the divergence of the sequence, not the associated series.

Comment: Yes it seems about sequences!

Answer (score 0):

We have that eventually $6^n \ge n+5^n$ therefore

$$a_n = \frac{9^n}{n + 5^n}\ge \frac{9^n}{6^n}=\left(\frac32\right)^n\to \infty$$

indeed by induction

- $n=1\implies 6\ge 1+5$
- assuming $6^n \ge n+5^n$ true we have

$$6^{n+1}=6\cdot 6^n\ge 6n+6\cdot 5^n\ge (n+1)+5^{n+1}$$